# NewSequentialId - pure net core 2.2 implementation of sql server function

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

i'm currently trying to rewrite sql server newSequentialId() function in pure c# that is performing as fast as possible and eats minimum memory.

Question is can I it be done better - current benchamark shows it is at most 2x slower than native function used by SqlServer (p/invoke)?

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;

namespace PerfBenchmarkDotNet
{
    internal static class FastGuid
    {
        private static readonly byte[] macBytes;
        private static long baseDateTicks;

        private static long ClockSequenceNumber = 0;


        static FastGuid()
        {
            macBytes = GetDefaultMacAdress();
            baseDateTicks = new DateTime(1582, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
        }

        public static Guid NewGuid()
        {
            var guidArray = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(16);
            var nowTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            var sequenceNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref ClockSequenceNumber) % 65536;

            var ticksDiff = nowTicks - baseDateTicks;
            var ticksDiffBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ticksDiff);

            // Copy the bytes into the guid 

            // mac
            guidArray[15] = macBytes[5];
            guidArray[14] = macBytes[4];
            guidArray[13] = macBytes[3];
            guidArray[12] = macBytes[2];
            guidArray[11] = macBytes[1];
            guidArray[10] = macBytes[0];

            // sequence number
            guidArray[8] = (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8);
            guidArray[9] = (byte)(sequenceNumber);

            // time
            guidArray[7] = ticksDiffBytes[0];
            guidArray[6] = ticksDiffBytes[1];
            guidArray[5] = ticksDiffBytes[2];
            guidArray[4] = ticksDiffBytes[3];
            guidArray[3] = ticksDiffBytes[4];
            guidArray[2] = ticksDiffBytes[5];
            guidArray[1] = ticksDiffBytes[6];
            guidArray[0] = ticksDiffBytes[7];

            var guid = new Guid(guidArray);

            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(guidArray);

            return guid;
        }

        private static byte[] GetDefaultMacAdress()
        {
            var nic = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();

            if (nic != null)
            {
                return nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
            }

            var fallback = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
            return fallback.Take(6).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to benchmark against [this](https://github.com/phatboyg/NewId) library?

Comment: Yup, newid is very fast and it looks like a have to do better ;)

Answer (score 7):

You want to reduce both computation time and memory allocation. Memory allocation itself takes time, so that's a good place to start -- try to find all the places where you're allocating memory and see if they can be avoided.

`ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(16);` *can* avoid an allocation, but not always. Can we do better? Turns out we can; we'll see how.

`BitConverter.GetBytes(ticksDiff)` makes an allocation. `ticksDiff` is just an integer so it's quite easy to extract its binary representation using binary operators. We'll see how we can use this later on.

But first:

## Profiling

Profilers are your friend! You should always start the optimization journey by asking "Where are the bottlenecks?", which you can promptly answer with cold hard data from a profiling tool.

As suspected, dotTrace reports that the `ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent/Return` and `BitConverter.GetBytes(ticksDiff)` calls take a significant chunk (~21%) of the total running time. Let's get rid of those.

## Guid constructor

You're using the `Guid` constructor that takes a `byte[]`, which has perpetuated an implementation that necessarily allocates a byte array *somewhere*. You can get clever with this to allocate on the stack instead of the heap (`Span<byte>` with `stackalloc`) or to minimize the number of allocations that actually need to happen (`ThreadLocal<byte[]>`), but the best solution is to *not allocate anything at all*. To accomplish this, you can use one of the other `Guid` constructors that takes its values directly, instead of taking a byte array.

There's a constructor overload that takes an `int`, two `short`s, and eight `byte`s. You can pack these values directly (see the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/guid.cs) for endianness on the `int` and `short`s):

```
int a = ticksDiffBytes[7] | (ticksDiffBytes[6] << 8) | (ticksDiffBytes[5] << 16) | (ticksDiffBytes[4] << 24);
short b = (short)(ticksDiffBytes[3] | (ticksDiffBytes[2] << 8));
short c = (short)(ticksDiffBytes[1] | (ticksDiffBytes[0] << 8));

var guid = new Guid(
    a,
    b,
    c,
    (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8),
    (byte)(sequenceNumber),
    macBytes[0],
    macBytes[1],
    macBytes[2],
    macBytes[3],
    macBytes[4],
    macBytes[5]);
```

## Binary stuff

You can extract bits directly from `ticksDiff` to avoid the call to `BitConverter.GetBytes`:

```
var ticksDiff = nowTicks - baseDateTicks;

int a = (int)(
    ((ticksDiff >> 56) & 0xFF) |
    ((ticksDiff & 0x00FF000000000000) >> 40) |
    ((ticksDiff & 0x0000FF0000000000) >> 24) |
    ((ticksDiff & 0x000000FF00000000) >> 8));

short b = (short)(
    ((ticksDiff & 0x00000000FF000000) >> 24) |
    ((ticksDiff & 0x0000000000FF0000) >> 8));

short c = (short)(
    ((ticksDiff & 0x000000000000FF00) >> 8) |
    ((ticksDiff & 0x00000000000000FF) << 8));
```

If you can tolerate a change in endianness, the following is a lot cleaner to read (but provides no measurable change in runtime for me):

```
var ticksDiff = nowTicks - baseDateTicks;

int a = (int)(ticksDiff);
short b = (short)(ticksDiff >> 32);
short c = (short)(ticksDiff >> 48);
```

## Remainder

You don't need to do a remainder when computing `sequenceNumber` because we're extracting the remainder bits directly anyhow when we pass `(byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8), (byte)(sequenceNumber)` to the `Guid` constructor.

My numbers below make it hard to conclude if this helps at all. This is the kind of thing that might be optimized away by the jitter anyway.

## Benchmarks

With these changes, my benchmarks look as follows:

```
|                                    Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev | Ratio |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------------------------------------ |---------:|--------:|--------:|------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|                          NewGuid_Original | 224.2 ns | 4.37 ns | 4.49 ns |  1.00 | 0.0041 |     - |     - |      20 B |
|                  NewGuid_WithPackedValues | 153.6 ns | 2.51 ns | 2.35 ns |  1.00 | 0.0041 |     - |     - |      20 B |
| NewGuid_WithPackedValuesAndNoBitConverter | 148.6 ns | 2.43 ns | 2.28 ns |  1.00 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|                NewGuid_WithReorderedBytes | 148.9 ns | 2.92 ns | 3.00 ns |  1.00 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|  NewGuid_WithReorderedBytesAndNoRemainder | 146.4 ns | 2.11 ns | 1.98 ns |  1.00 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
```

Final code:

```
public static Guid NewGuid_WithBinaryOptimizationsAndWithoutRemainder()
{
    var nowTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
    var sequenceNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref ClockSequenceNumber);

    var ticksDiff = nowTicks - baseDateTicks;

    int a = (int)(ticksDiff);
    short b = (short)(ticksDiff >> 32);
    short c = (short)(ticksDiff >> 48);

    var guid = new Guid(
        a,
        b,
        c,
        (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8),
        (byte)(sequenceNumber),
        macBytes[0],
        macBytes[1],
        macBytes[2],
        macBytes[3],
        macBytes[4],
        macBytes[5]);

    return guid;
}
```

Comment: how did u format benchmark results?

Comment: I used BenchmarkDotNet which does the table formatting by default.

Answer (score 1):

So after updating my source code it looks that it performs fast enough and allocates no memory. Here are benchmark for comparing the most popular methods of generating GUIDs.

> Runtime=.NET Core 3.0  Force=True  Server=True
>
> ```cs
> |                              Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
> |------------------------------------ |----------:|---------:|---------:|------:|--------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
> |          SqlServerNewSequentialGuid |  38.69 ns | 0.787 ns | 1.643 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 | 0.0009 |     - |     - |      80 B |
> |                       Guid_Standard |  61.44 ns | 0.665 ns | 0.622 ns |  1.60 |    0.06 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
> |        NHibernate_GuidCombGenerator | 160.22 ns | 3.070 ns | 2.721 ns |  4.16 |    0.20 | 0.0012 |     - |     - |     104 B |
> |                       Guid_Comb_New | 291.56 ns | 5.421 ns | 4.805 ns |  7.57 |    0.37 | 0.0010 |     - |     - |     104 B |
> | EFCore_SequentialGuidValueGenerator |  82.04 ns | 1.623 ns | 1.667 ns |  2.13 |    0.11 | 0.0007 |     - |     - |      72 B |
> |                           NewId_Lib |  78.93 ns | 1.150 ns | 1.076 ns |  2.05 |    0.09 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
> |       NewSequentialGuid_PureNetCore |  70.28 ns | 1.332 ns | 1.481 ns |  1.81 |    0.08 |      - |     - |     - |         - |
> ```

Full source code in c# .net core 2.2+:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;

namespace PerfBenchmarkDotNet
{
    internal readonly struct FastGuid
    {
        private static readonly byte[] _macBytes;
        private static long _baseDateTicks;
        private static long _clockSequenceNumber;

        static FastGuid()
        {
            _clockSequenceNumber = 0;
            _macBytes = GetDefaultMacAdress();
            _baseDateTicks = new DateTime(1582, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
        }

        public static Guid NewGuid()
        {
            var nowTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            var sequenceNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref _clockSequenceNumber);
            var ticksDiff = nowTicks - _baseDateTicks;

            var a = (int)(ticksDiff);
            short b = (short)(ticksDiff >> 32);
            short c = (short)(ticksDiff >> 48);

            return new Guid(
                a,
                b,
                c,
                (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8),
                (byte)(sequenceNumber),
                _macBytes[0],
                _macBytes[1],
                _macBytes[2],
                _macBytes[3],
                _macBytes[4],
                _macBytes[5]);
        }

        private static byte[] GetDefaultMacAdress()
        {
            var nic = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();

            if (nic != null)
            {
                return nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
            }

            var fallback = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
            return fallback.Take(6).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how you profiled SqlServerNewSequentialGuid (`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`) since that can only be used in a default constraint expression, AFAIK.